# How do I get the org.apache.catalina.connector.Request object in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I need to write a Servlet or Filter class that can get access to the org.apache.catalina.connector.Request object, which is wrapped in the RequestFacade object given to my servlet. Casting doesn't work, since RequestFacade is not a subclass of Request.

The reason I need this is because I am trying to call the setRequestedSessionId() method of Request, and this is apparently not part of the Http servlet spec. The reason I need to do this is because the session ID is being included in a URL under a different name than JSESSIONID. I can't change the URL or the name of the parameter, so I'm trying to associate the request with the correct session by extracting the session ID and call Request.setRequestedSessionId().

I have actually solved the problem using a Valve subclass, but I don't like using a Valve because as far as I can tell, I need to install my Valve subclass in the Tomcat/server/classes directory instead of packaging it with the rest of my webapp. If there was a portable way to do this across different Servlet containers, that would be great, but at the moment I'm resigned to making this Tomcat-specific.

Here is the working Valve code:

```
public class SessionSetter extends ValveBase {
public void invoke( Request request, Response response ) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String sessionId = request.getParameter( "whatever" );
    request.setRequestedSessionId( sessionId );
}
```

}

Is there some way to do the same thing in a Servlet or Filter? Or is there some way to package the Valve class in my application .war file?

Comment: Why do I need to do what? I thought I stated the reasons in the second paragraph, please let me know which part I didn't explain well.

Comment: If you're using Tomcat 6 then this might be an alternative you could look at: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/systemprops.html#Sessions. You can change the names used for session id parameter using system properties. It's not available for Tomcat 7 though as far as I can tell (I think the servlet spec that tc7 implements is stricter about changing the name).

Comment: Hi Matt - we're using Tomcat 5.5, so I don't know if we can rely on this tweak, but that is really slick! Much nicer solution than what I was trying to do. I'll look into whether Tomcat 5.5 supports it.

Comment: I just checked; it is configurable in 5.5 as well, so that will work perfectly for us. If you want to repost as an answer I will mark that as the accepted answer so you can get credit. I'm still curious though if there is some way to get access to the Request object in case I need to call methods on it directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(this is my comment upgraded to an answer)

If you're using Tomcat 5.5 or 6 then this might be an alternative you could look at: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/systemprops.html#Sessions. You can change the names used for session id parameter using system properties. It's not available for Tomcat 7 though as far as I can tell (I think the servlet spec that tc7 implements is stricter about changing the name).

As for accessing the Tomcat internal request object from your webapp (servlet or filter), I don't think you'll be able to. I seem to recall reading somewhere that the RequestFacade class exists explicitly to prevent that, so that a webapp can't mess with the the Tomcat internals.

Answer (score 5):

Tomcat stores the real **Request** object in the protected variable **request** of **RequestFacade**, so you can get it (in a Servlet or JSP) with [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;

...

Field f = request.getClass().getDeclaredField("request");
f.setAccessible(true); // grant access to (protected) field
Request realRequest = (Request)f.get(request);
```

Comment: Note this won't work if a Java security manager is in place to restrict setAccessible.